# A straightforward Perforce migration to git on Windows

Tags: git, migration, perforce, bitbucket

I have a local p4 server on my computer to manage my code versioning.
I would like to move my development to Bitbucket - so I've opened an account there.

The first logical kickoff, as I see it, would be migrating the P4 environment to git (while keeping all history of course) - which seems to be a headache for the unpracticed git user.

1. I've tried git-p4 from git bash, but git for windows is apparently compiled w/o Python.
2. Got git-p4.py. Tried (in cmd): git-p4.py clone //depot/foo/bar/@all //opt/dest/. Got "libiconv-2.dll is missing" error. Then I've stopped because I think that I'm doing something entirely wrong.

Please help me understand how to do it right...
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

@Mark,

Sorry to hear you ran into an error.

One way is to use Git-Fusion. If you follow all the steps in the Quickstart guide:

http://answers.perforce.com/articles/KB_Article/Git-Fusion-Quick-Start

there is a section on 'Creating a Git Fusion repo' to guide you in creating a Git repo from your Perforce server.  Keep in mind, you cannot skip steps and must do all the install and configuration to get Git-Fusion up and running.

The Git Fusion Guide also has a section on 'Setting up Repos':

http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/git-fusion/chapter_dyn_ngj_3l.html

There is also a Troubleshooting section in the Git Fusion guide. For example, if the Perforce server is on Windows or Mac there could be case issues:

http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/git-fusion/chapter_ipm_rdw_w3.html#section_btc_d4f_cl

There is a message early in the install/configuration process that will bring it to the admin's attention.  The Perforce service's case-handling policy is not set to 'sensitive', which means any files introduced via Git whose names differ only by case may result in data loss or errors during push. It is strongly advised to set the case-handling policy to 'sensitive'. To bypass this check, pass --ignore-case when invoking this script.

If you do run into case problems when cloning a repo out of your server, you can use p4migrate (ftp://ftp.perforce.com/perforce/tools/p4-migrate/p4migrate.html) to create case-consistent metadata, and then try again. You can download p4migrate from the Perforce ftp site: ftp://ftp.perforce.com/perforce/tools/p4-migrate/

I hope this helps some. You can contact support@perforce.com for further assistance and let them know your setup.